# UI5 MatrixLayout with 2 columns in XML View

Tags: xml, layout, matrix, sapui5

I try to make a MatrixLayout with 1 colum containing 2 lines of text and 1 column with a line of text and an Icon.

At the moment it looks like this:

[image: MatrixLayout]

1. Problem: The Icon is floated to the right of the text element, but should bbe positioned under the text. Why is this?
2. Problem: The columns widths are 50% / 50%, I need them to be 30% / 70%. I tried to set the property "widths" for the MatrixLayout, but in my XML view I cannot set them like `widths="[30%, 70%]"`because then console says:

> Uncaught Error: "[30%, 70%]" is of type object, expected sap.ui.core.CSSSize[] for property "widths" of Element sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayout#__layout1

The snippet from the view:

```
<layout:MatrixLayout 
                            layoutFixed="false"
                            columns="2"
                            width="100%"
                            widths="10%, 90%"
                            >
                            <layout:MatrixLayoutRow>                            
                            <layout:cells>
                                <layout:MatrixLayoutCell>
                                    <Text width="80%" maxLines="1" clampHeight="1" text="lululajksdhkajsdh askdahksdhahsdjkahjksdhasd kjahsdkjahsdhasjkdhasjd ">
                                    </Text>
                                    <Text width="80%" maxLines="1" clampHeight="1" text="lululajksdhkajsdh askdahksdhahsdjkahjksdhasd kjahsdkjahsdhasjkdhasjd ">
                                    </Text>
                                </layout:MatrixLayoutCell>
                                <layout:MatrixLayoutCell>
                                    <Text width="80%" maxLines="1" clampHeight="1" text="lululajksdhkajsdh askdahksdhahsdjkahjksdhasd kjahsdkjahsdhasjkdhasjd ">
                                    </Text>
                                    <core:Icon src="sap-icon://add"></core:Icon>
                                </layout:MatrixLayoutCell>
                            </layout:cells>                 
                            </layout:MatrixLayoutRow>
                         </layout:MatrixLayout>
```

What do I do wrong? Thanks..

Comment: about Problem 2 try ["30%","70%"] ... regards

Comment: @zyrex also not working, XML needs open quotes to parse value, I also tried "['30%', '70%']" same error as mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can specify it in the XMLView directly -- since it's an array, I don't think you can specify it directly in an attribute

However, if you specify an ID for your `MatrixLayout` you could of course perfectly set it using the controller:

```
onAfterRendering: function() {
    this.byId("myMatrixLayout").setWidths(["30%", "70%"]);
}
```

EDIT: I also noticed you are setting multiple controls in a `MatrixLayoutCell`.
Although that may work, it is generally better to have each control in its own cell, for better control of the layout:

```
<l:MatrixLayout id="myLayout">
    <l:MatrixLayoutRow>
        <l:MatrixLayoutCell><Text text="In pharetra diam pretium bibendum" /></l:MatrixLayoutCell>
        <l:MatrixLayoutCell><Text text="Sed tristique diam non imperdiet commodo" /></l:MatrixLayoutCell>
    </l:MatrixLayoutRow>
    <l:MatrixLayoutRow>
        <l:MatrixLayoutCell><Text text="At tincidunt purus finibus" /></l:MatrixLayoutCell>
        <l:MatrixLayoutCell><core:Icon src="sap-icon://add" /></l:MatrixLayoutCell>
    </l:MatrixLayoutRow>
</l:MatrixLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can specify it in the XMLView directly

```
<l:MatrixLayout xmlns="sap.ui.commons"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    columns="3"
    widths="50%,40%,10%">
    <l:rows></l:rows>
</l:MatrixLayout>
```